# Uncaught syntax error in Id_conversion_map["1"] = ;

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop-1.6

There is an error in my source code which I don't understand. It says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

In the source code I find this incorrect code missing expressions:

```
ld_conversion_map["1"] = ;
ld_conversion_map["5"] = ;
ld_conversion_map["6"] = ;
ld_conversion_map["es"] = ;
ld_conversion_map["gb"] = ;
ld_conversion_map["fi"] = ;
```

But it is missing the expressions. I don't know where this code comes from and how to resolve it.
My website is http://clubvapea.es

Comment: or you dont use the "=" or you assign something to dat vars

Comment: `ld_conversion_map["1"] = undefined;` or `ld_conversion_map["1"] = '';`

Comment: Information is not enough to give solution for this bug. Please add some more code. `ld_conversion_map["1"] = ;` here in these you are not assigning value , there must be some value on the right side of `=` symbol to assign value in left side defined variable.

Comment: There is no match for a search of `ld_conversion_map` in github code, so the error probably comes from a purchased module.

Comment: Is there a way to search this piece of code through FTP on the files of my site? You may see for yourself in http://clubvapea.es Thank you for all asnwers

Answer (score 0):

of-course the syntax is incorrect from first line till end.
following are your options.

```
ld_conversion_map["1"] = '';
ld_conversion_map["1"] = null;
ld_conversion_map["1"] = undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

An expression like `ld_conversion_map["1"] = ;` is a *syntax error* because an assignment should have a value on the right hand side of the the `=` operator.

It appears you didn't write that code yourself, I checked your site. Or did you?

I suppose it's PrestaShop's code, in this case you should report the bug to them.

Other things you can do are:

1. dig into the CMS source and determine what it is they're trying to do there and fix it.
2. If all that bothers you is the sight of the error, then do this where necessary: `ld_conversion_map["1"] = null;`.
3. If nothing is broken on your site due to this bug, you may ignore it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't write that code, but I would like to know if there is a way to know where does that piece of code come from, so that it can be fixed. Developers fro Google Analytics told me that analytics is not working because these expressions are missing, so the code after this cannot be read correctly.

Comment: This error is not shown when I disable all non-native modules, so it must be one of the modules. But I tried one by one disabling all modules but it didn't work. Prestashop is telling me I have to pay 599$ if I need technical support...

Comment: So is there a way to know where this code comes from?

Answer (score 0):

I found finally where this code came from. It is Language and currency detection by IP from Presto-Changeo cauding all this trouble. Thank you for your answers!